# Divide seaborn matrix by lines according to clustering

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, heatmap, seaborn

[This paper](http://web.mit.edu/cocosci/Papers/shafto_etal_cogsci06.pdf) has a nice way of visualizing clusters of a dataset with binary features by plotting a 2D matrix and sorting the values according to a cluster.

[image: clusters]

In this case, there are three clusters, as indicated by the black dividing lines; the rows are sorted, and show which examples are in each cluster, and the columns are the features of each example.

Given a vector of cluster assignments and a pandas DataFrame, how can I replicate this using a Python library (e.g. seaborn)? Plotting a DataFrame using seaborn isn't difficult, nor is sorting the rows of the DataFrame to align with the cluster assignments. What I am most interested in is how to display those black dividing lines which delineate each cluster.

Dummy data:

```
"""
       col1  col2
x1_c0     0     1
x2_c0     0     1
================= I want a line drawn here
x3_c1     1     0
================= and here
x4_c2     1     0
"""
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={'col1': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'col2': [1, 1, 0, 0]},
    index=['x1_c0', 'x2_c0', 'x3_c1', 'x4_c2']
)
clus = [0, 0, 1, 2]  # This is the cluster assignment

sns.heatmap(df)
```

[image]

Comment: See  [this example](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/network_correlations.html)

Answer (score 2):

The link that mwaskom posted in a comment is good starting place. The trick is figuring out what the coordinates are for the vertical and horizontal lines.

To illustrate what the code is actually doing, it's worthwhile to just plot all of the lines individually

```
%matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'col2': [1, 1, 0, 0]},
                  index=['x1_c0', 'x2_c0', 'x3_c1', 'x4_c2'])

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

sns.heatmap(df)

ax.axvline(1, 0, 2, linewidth=3, c='w')
ax.axhline(1, 0, 1, linewidth=3, c='w')
ax.axhline(2, 0, 1, linewidth=3, c='w')
ax.axhline(3, 0, 1, linewidth=3, c='w')

f.tight_layout()
```

[image]

The the way that the `axvline` method works is the first argument is the x location of the line and then the lower bound and upper bound of the line (in this case 1, 0, 2). The horizontal line takes the y location and then the x start and x stop of the line. The defaults will create the line for the entire plot, so you can typically leave those out.

This code above creates a line for *every* value in the dataframe. If you want to create groups for the heatmap, you will want to create an index in your data frame, or some other list of values to loop through. For instance with a more complicated example using code from [this example](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/network_correlations.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1.5], 'col2': [1, 1, 0, 0, 2]},
                  index=['x1_c0', 'x2_c0', 'x3_c1', 'x4_c2', 'x5_c2'])

df['id_'] = df.index
df['group'] = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
df.set_index(['group', 'id_'], inplace=True)
df

             col1  col2
group id_
1     x1_c0   0.0     1
2     x2_c0   0.0     1
      x3_c1   1.0     0
3     x4_c2   1.0     0
      x5_c2   1.5     2
```

Then plot the heatmap with the groups:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

sns.heatmap(df)

groups = df.index.get_level_values(0)

for i, group in enumerate(groups):
    if i and group != groups[i - 1]:
        ax.axhline(len(groups) - i, c="w", linewidth=3)

ax.axvline(1, c="w", linewidth=3)

f.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Because your heatmap is not symmetric you may need to use a separate for loop for the columns